# How to play remote video fluently on Apple TV in low bandwidth

Tags: swift, video, stream, avplayer, tvos

I have developed an tvOS app for playing Vimeo video. The average of the videos are 800 MB. It works fine when the bandwidth is > 90 Mbits/s. But when it is 35 Mbits/s, the performance of the video playing is not so good: sound doesn't sync with the images.

I use a class inherited from the standard `AVPlayerViewController` to play the video.

```
//Playing the video from the download link for the video

func playVimeoVideo(link : String) {

    player = AVPlayer(URL: NSURL(string: link)!)   
    player?.play()
}
```

Do you have any ideas on how to improve the performance when the bandwidth is low? I wonder if I should download the video before I play it but then it might take too long.